# Read the return value of a method using javassist

Tags: javassist

I want to read the return value of a method which  and I have to pass it to the code that I insert using method.insertAfter.

Example:

```
public String sayHello(){
    return "1";
}
```

I want to add the code say, someClass.someMethod() using javassist.

```
method.insertAfter("someClass.someMethod(<how to add that value here>);");
```

Can anyone let me know how to do this?

[Edit]
I cannot edit the method body since there might be other code present. The above method is just an example.

Comment: Not sure if I understood you completely, but for what you want I think it will be easier for you to rename the method sayHello to sayHello_modified and then create a new sayHello method that in the body  calls the sayHello_modified sends it's result  to someClass.someMethod, returning the return in the end. Would this be acceptable for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    method.insertAfter( "System.err.println( $_ );");
```

If the method returns void, then $_ will be null.
So, in your case, I think this will work:

```
    method.insertAfter( "someClass.someMethod( $_ );");
```

where someMethod takes an Object.

Comment: I went with @pabrantes solution in the comments section. That did the trick.. I will try out this one too....